# MERN delete data undefined at backend

Tags: reactjs, express, redux-toolkit

I am trying to implement a delete functionality in my MERN App, but whenever I try to send my `delete IDs` to backend controller the `Delete ID Array` is Undefined

`deletePosts` is an array of IDs to delete  `deletePosts = [id1, id2, id3 ...]`

React Posts Component:-

```
function AllPosts() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  
  const { posts, isSuccess } = useSelector((state) => state.posts);

  
  const handleDelete = () => {
    dispatch(deletePost({deletePosts}));
  };

  return (
                <>
                      {posts.map((post, index) => (
                        <Post
                          postId={post._id}
                          subject={post.subject}
                          handleDelete={handleDelete}
                        />
                      ))}
                
                </>
    
  )}

export default AllPosts;
```

Redux Toolkit Slice:-

```
export const deletePost = createAsyncThunk(
    "posts/delete",
    async (postDelete, thunkAPI) => {
      try {
        
        const token = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("token"));
    
        return await postService.deletePost(postDelete, token);
    
    } catch (error) {
        const message =
          (error.response &&
            error.response.data &&
            error.response.data.message) ||
          error.message ||
          error.toString();
  
        return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue(message);
      }
    }
  );
```

REDUX Toolkit Service:-

```
const deletePost = async (postDelete, token) => {
    const config = {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
      },
    };
  
    
    const response = await axios.delete(API_URL, postDelete, config);
        
    return response.data;
  
};
```

ROUTE:-

```
router.route("/").delete(protect, deletePost)
```

CONTROLLER:-

```
const deletePost = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
    console.log("Delete Controller:-  ", req.body);

    /****
     * 
     *    Delete Logic 
     * 
     * 
     */
  
  });
```

CONTROLLER console.log:-

```
Delete Controller:-  {}
```

Data is passed from `Component > Slice > Service > Route > Controller`

`the deletePosts array has content of Ids till REDUX toolkit Service` but in the controller is shows `Undefined`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this will solve your problem:

```
const deletePost = async (postDelete, token) => {
    const config = {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
      },
      data:{
          postDelete 
      }
    };  
    const response = await axios.delete(API_URL, config);      
    return response.data;
};
```

Also you are sending your deleted as an object, if this is not intended please change the following in your react posts component

```
const handleDelete = () => {
  dispatch(deletePost(deletePosts)); // ({deletePosts}) will give you an object of deleted posts in the destination instead of an array

};
```

Comment: yes this worked thank you and yes deletePosts was not intended as an object.